# CSS styles for all the different UL uses

Tags: css, bem, oocss

The `ul` tag is very generic and something I continually struggle with.

Initially I had a base style rule defined for my `ul` and `li` tags to handle bullet points in my generic text blocks for WYSIWYG text.
I am using BEM so I figured I would just add a class to any `ul` which had a different role (*say a menu, or a list of news thumbnails, etc.*)

The problem is that I don't always have control over the markup; my current problem is a pagination plugin which uses a `ul/li` structure but doesn't allow me add a class to the `ul`.

I am using BEM so I don't really want to use descendant selectors, and especially element selectors, but I realise I will probably need to do so when I don't have access to the `ul/li` markup.

Any advice would be appreciated - especially with base/rest rules, as I have `ul/li` lists all over the place in so many sites and once and for all want to master this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question? You can style each `<ul>` like you like it using class names following BEM. When you can't append classes to certain elements of your page you may only use descendant selectors. The only alterantive is to append classes via javscript, to be very strict.

Comment: Sorry I know it was long-winded,but my question is kind of the last paragraph. js is not a viable solution. How can I target a ul with just a descendant selector -it would have to be a element selector?

Comment: you have multiple choices. you can use a type selector like this: `.parent > ul` or a sibling selector `.previous + ul`  or a pseduo class if you are sure about the html structure `.parent :first-child`

Comment: If you can't add custom "BEM-classes" to your HTML, there is no way to make it 100% BEM.

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

- Reset the styles for ul/li with a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/);
- Make an exception in your BEM principles, and use a cascade for the formatted text. Example:

CSS:

```
.text ul {
    list-style: circle;
}
.text li {
    margin: .5em 1em;
}
.text p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/* etc. */
```

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
    <p>Here all the text is formatted</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may be right about making an exception for BEM. That's currently what I am doing - though I don't like that I have some BEM and some cascade.

Comment: BEM is not a good way to style formatted texts, because a clean text is a text with as less CSS classes as possible. Using a cascade prevents to reuse the block inside itself. But a formatted text can not be included in another formatted text. A tag `<p>` cannot be nested in another `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Tarh

So this comes up with WordPress theme dev all the time. All content areas get generic element that you can't attach classes too. So you have two solutions here:

1. Like Tarh describes above, you use a reset to kill all styles on UL/LI, and you only use BEM for styling them through out your site. But when you reach the content areas that don't allow you to add classes to elements, you just wrap the whole content area in a div with the BEM class of your liking, and you follow the steps above.

2.In WP there is a little know way to handle this, but it requires writing some functions. You can [read about how to do this here](http://www.carriedils.com/add-editor-style/). Basically, you make the hidden formatting dropdown visible, then you hide the default "paragraph/heading" dropdown hidden. Then you can format generic elements however you want.  Like:

```
array(
  'title' => 'Large heading',
  'block' => 'ul',
  'classes' => 'content__list'
)
```

But I don't know if you are actually referring to WP stuff, so I'm just going to end this here.

Best of luck! Stay awesome!